# Any tool for easily outlining coordinates of a shape in a raster image?

Tags: images

I have to get coordinate data for all corners in a polygon in a raster image.

This is going into an `area` element like this:

```
<area shape='poly' coords='x1,y1,x2,y2,...'/>
```

Is there any simple tool that enables

- drawing the shape on the image by hand
- getting all corners coordinates

I know that I can get coordinates easily with any image editor but you have to do it one point at a time and *I want to avoid this*.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Image Map Editor for such a thing. See http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap for example and select "Polygon" after drawing the rectangle. You get the coordinates then.

Comment: Thank you, this one is interesting. I am also looking for non-commercial, offline tools, because we need to do this on workstations that are not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Maybe one of those listed here could give you the offline functionality you like: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Image_map_resources#Image_Map_Editors

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that Gimp has a plugin that is usually included in distributions (Web-Imagemap) and this is cool...

Answer (score 0):

I have found an online open source project, called [ImageMap](http://code.google.com/p/imagemap/), hosted on Google Code. It is an AJAX, WYSIWYG, editor that does it.